# Efficiently computing the first 20-digit substring to repeat in the decimal expansion of Pi

Tags: algorithm

### Problem

Pi = 3.14159 **26** 5358979323846 **26** 433... so the first 2-digit substring to repeat is 26.

What is an efficient way of finding the first 20-digit substring to repeat?

### Constraints

- I have about 500 gigabytes of digits of Pi (1 byte per digit), and about 500 gigabytes of disk space free.
- I have about 5 gigabytes of RAM free.
- I am interested in an efficient algorithm that would work for arbitrary sequences rather than the specific answer for Pi itself.  In other words, I am not interested in a solution of the form "print 123....456" even if the number it prints is correct.

### What I've tried

I place each substring into a hash table and report the first collision.

(The hash table is constructed as an array of sorted linked lists.  The index into the array is given by the bottom digits of the string (converted to an integer), and the value stored in each node is the location in the expansion of Pi where the substring first appeared.)

This worked fine until I ran out of RAM.

To scale to longer sequences I have considered:

- Generating the hash for all substrings starting in a certain range, and then continuing the search over the remainder of the digits.  This needs to rescan the entire sequence of Pi for each range, so becomes order N^2
- Bucket sorting the set of 20-digit substrings to multiple files, and then using a hash table to find the first repeat in each file separately.  Unfortunately, with this method I run out of disk space so would need 20 passes through the data.  (If I start with 1000 digits, then I will end up with 1000 20-digit substrings.)
- Storing 2 digits of Pi per byte to free up more memory.
- Adding a disk-based backing store to my hash table.  I worry that this would behave very poorly as there is no obvious locality of reference.

Is there a better approach?

### Update

1. I tried Adrian McCarthy's qsort method but this seemed a little slower than hashing for finding duplicates
2. I looked at btilly's MapReduce suggestion for parallelising the algorithm but it was heavily IO bound on my single computer so not appropriate for me (with my single disk drive)
3. I implemented supercat's method to spend last night splitting the files and searching for 19 digit substrings in the first 18 billion digits.
4. This found 16 matches so I used Jarred's suggestion to re-check the 19 digit matches to find the first 20 digit match

To search 18 billion digits took
3 hours to split the files, and 40 minutes to then rescan the files looking for matches.

### Answer

The 20-digit substring 84756845106452435773 is found at positions 1,549,4062,637 and 17,601,613,330 within the decimal expansion of Pi.

Many thanks everyone!

Comment: What advantage do you see in these complex approaches? I haven't thought about it in detail, but I'd have thought that pi's digits are near enough to random that walking through the digits linearly would be as efficient as anything....

Comment: The only advantage I am trying for is speed.  All the approaches I have tried take a long time to complete.  If there is a simple linear approach that I have missed please post some pseudocode as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: What a cool problem!  Do you have any preferred implementation languages/environments?

Comment: My current code is C to try to get the best speed but I am quite happy to use most languages/environments (except x86 assembler) if they are well suited for the problem (e.g. perhaps some languages have some excellent scaling hashing libraries builtin?).

Comment: Might the matching substrings overlap?  For example, if then sequence "012345678901234567890123456789", is that two 20-digit matching substrings?

Comment: They can overlap, although I would be utterly astonished if the answer actually involved an overlap!

Comment: I'm not convinced that hashing substrings in ranges really leads to O(N^2).  If N is the number of digits in your expansion of pi and M is the number of subranges, then it's O(N*M) -- one pass over pi for each subrange.  Since the hash table memory requirement decreases as 1/M, it seems like you should be able to choose M << N.

Comment: You may well be right, I am not an expert on complexity theory!  I guess it depends on whether you consider that RAM size increases with N.  I could see myself buying another hard disk, but installing more memory sounds harder so I was considering that the RAM size was fixed.  In this case the number of ranges is proportional to N (roughly N/5,000,000,000) and so I thought the total order would be O(N*M)=O(N*N/5,000,000,000)=O(N^2).

Comment: Hey, this is a great question!  Keep it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data set is pretty big, so some sort of "divide and conquer" will be necessary.  I would suggest that as a first step, you subdivide the problem into some number of pieces (e.g. 100).  Start by seeing if the file has any duplicated 20-digit sequences start with 00, then see if it has any starting with 01, etc. up to 99.  Start each of these "main passes" by writing out to a file all of the 20-digit sequences that start with the correct number.  If the first two digits are constant, you'll only need to write out the last 18; since an 18-digit decimal number will fit into an 8-byte 'long', the output file will probably hold about 5,000,000,000 numbers, taking up 40GB of disk space.  Note that it may be worthwhile to produce more than one output file at a time, so as to avoid having to read every byte of the source file 100 times, but disk performance may be better if you are simply reading one file and writing one file.

Once one has generated the data file for a particular "main pass", one must then determine whether there are any duplicates in it.  Subdividing it into some number of smaller sections based upon the bits in the numbers stored therein may be a good next step.  If one subdivides it into 256 smaller sections, each section will have somewhere around 16-32 million numbers; the five gigabytes of RAM one has could be used to buffer a million numbers for each of the 256 buckets.  Writing out each chunk of a million numbers would require a random disk seek, but the number of such writes would be pretty reasonable (probably about 10,000 disk seeks).

Once the data has been subdivided into files of 16-32 million numbers each, simply read each such file into memory and look for duplicates.

The algorithm as described probably isn't optimal, but it should be reasonably close.  Of greatest interest is the fact that cutting in half the number of main passes would cut in half the number of times one had to read through the source data file, but would more than double the time required to process each pass once its data had been copied.  I would guess that using 100 passes through the source file probably isn't optimal, but the time required for the overall process using that split factor would be pretty close to the time using the optimal split factor.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like a good solution that matches my constraints.  As far as I understand it, your solution is based on the bucket sorting approach I was considering with three great improvements: 1) Don't bother storing the first digits of the substring that have been used to split into files, 2) Store multiple digits compressed to a binary number, 3) Instead of relying on the fwrite buffering when writing to multiple files, instead locally buffer big arrays of numbers to be written in a single burst.

Comment: Another improvement not mentioned: for the first level of splitting, discard much of the data on each pass, since it may be faster to read one file sequentially while writing one smaller file sequentially, than to read one file while writing many smaller ones; that would be especially advantageous if the files were on different disks.

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting problem.

First let's do some back of the envelope numbers.  Any particular sequence of 20 digits, will match one time in 10<sup>20</sup>.  If we go out to the n'th digit we have roughly n<sup>2</sup>/2 pairs of 20 digit sequences.  So to have good odds of finding a match we're going to probably need to have n a bit above 10<sup>10</sup>.  Assuming that we're taking 40 bytes per record, we're going to need something on the order of  400 GB of data.  (We actually need more data than this, so we should be prepared for something over a terabyte of data.)

That gives us an idea of the needed data volume.  Tens of billions of digits.  Hundreds of GB of data.

Now here is the problem.  If we use any data structure that requires random access, random access time is set by the disk speed.  Suppose that your disk goes at 6000 rpm.  That's 100 times per second.  On average the data you want is halfway around the disk.  So you get 200 random accesses per second on average.  (This can vary by hardware.)  Accessing it 10 billion times is going to take 50 million seconds, which is over a year.  If you read, then write, and wind up needing 20 billion data points - you're exceeding the projected lifetime of your hard drive.

The alternative is to process a batch of data in a way where you do not access randomly.  The classic is to do a good external sort such a merge-sort.  Suppose that we have 1 terabyte of data, which we read 30 times, write 30 times, during sorting.  (Both estimates are higher than needed, but I'm painting a worst case here.)  Suppose our harddrive has a sustained throughput of 100 MB/s.  Then each pass takes 10,000 seconds, for 600,000 seconds, which is slightly under a week.  This is very doable!  (In practice it should be faster than this.)

So here is the algorithm:

1. Start with a long list of digits, 3141...
2. Turn this into a much bigger file where each line is 20 digits, followed by the location where this appears in pi.
3. Sort this bigger file.
4. Search the sorted file for any duplications.

   1. If any are found, return the first.
   2. If none are found, repeat steps 1-3 with another big chunk of digits.
   3. Merge this into the previous sorted file.
   4. Repeat this search.

Now this is great, but what if we don't want to take a week?  What if we want to throw multiple machines at it?  This turns out to be surprisingly easy.  There are well-known distributed sorting algorithms.  If we split the initial file into chunks, we can parallelize both steps 1 and 4.  And if after step 4 we don't find a match, then we can just repeat from the start with a bigger input chunk.

In fact this pattern is very common. All that really varies is turning the initial data into stuff to be sorted, and then looking at matching groups.  This is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce algorithm.  And this will work just fine for this problem.

Comment: Thank you!  This looks like the best solution (in terms of only needing a few lines of code and very little wall time) for someone with access to multiple machines and lots of file storage.

Answer (score 4):

**Trie**

RBarryYoung has pointed out that this will exceed the memory limits.

A [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure might be appropriate.  In a single pass you can build up a trie with every prefix you've seen up to length n (e.g., n = 20).  As you continue to process, if you ever reach a node at level n that already exists, you've just found a duplicate substring.

**Suffix Matching**

Another approach involves treating the expansion as a character string.  This approach finds common suffixes, but you want common prefixes, so start by reversing the string.  Create an array of pointers, with each pointer pointing to the next digit in the string.  Then sort the pointers using a lexicographic sort.  In C, this would be something like:

```
qsort(array, number_of_digits, sizeof(array[0]), strcmp);
```

When the qsort finishes, similar substrings will be adjacent in the pointer array.  So for every pointer, you can do a limited string comparison with that string and the one pointed to by the next pointer.  Again, in C:

```
for (int i = 1; i < number_of_digits; ++i) {
  if (strncmp(array[i - 1], array[i], 20) == 0) {
    // found two substrings that match for at least 20 digits
    // the pointers point to the last digits in the common substrings
  }
}
```

The sort is (typically) O(n log_2 n), and the search afterwards is O(n).

This approach was inspired by [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/184404588).

Comment: An alternative to a trie that works well in low memory situations is a ternary tree.  I'm not adding it as a separate solution, though, since I like the trie as the first suggestion to start with, given the parameters of the problem.

Comment: The trie is going to be sparse in the second half of the 20-digits, and that will produce a lot of empty buckets, which for Tries means a *lot* of space consumption ( O(20/2 * 500GB) ), which will way overrun 5GB of memory.

Comment: @RBarryYoung:  I wouldn't attempt to preallocate a TRIE that can hold every possible path.  Allocate nodes as needed, and the sparseness will work in your favor.

Comment: @Adrian: No it won't work in your favor.  You will end up with billions of Trie buckets with only one (or two) entries each.  That's a memory worst-case for Tries (still fine computationally, though).

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Ah, I see your point now.  I have another idea.  I'll revise my answer.

Comment: I like the qsort idea!  Each of my nodes used 2 pointers (a pointer to the next node and a pointer to the digit in the string), while your approach only uses a single pointer so will be twice as space efficient.

Comment: I tried the qsort approach (using strncmp(left,right,20) for the sort function) but it seems a bit slower.  For the first 100 million digits of Pi it takes a total of 99 seconds (consisting of 7 seconds to load the data and prepare the array of pointers, followed by 90 seconds to sort the data and 2 seconds to find the best match).  For comparison, my current hashing approach takes a total of 20 seconds.

Comment: There is no way that the data set will fit in RAM, and a disk-based variant on your algorithm will take years to complete.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz: You don't want to limit the strcmp for the sort.  For one thing, you might get strong ordering.  But the other reason is that you'll miss out on even longer substring matches.  Yes, the sort is expensive (you'd probably need a memory mapped solution since the text is much larger than available memory), but once computed, you can find all matching substrings of all lengths.  See the article I linked to.

Comment: Ahh, many apologies, I hadn't realised the full power of your approach.  Using strcmp instead of strncmp doubles the speed to 47 seconds for 100 megabytes.  That is an exceptionally neat way of constructing a suffix array!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this will work:

1. Search for repeated substrings of length 2 (or some small base case), record starting indicies S={s_i}
2. For n=3..N, look for substrings of length n from the indices in S
3. Each iteration, update S with substrings of length n
4. at n=20, the first two indicies will be your answer

you might want to adjust the initial size and step size (it might not be necessary to step by 1 each time)

Comment: That looks like a promising approach!  I guess I can't start at length 2 because then all 500 billion 2-digit substrings would count as repeated substrings and I would run out of space to store S (or perhaps I have misunderstood your algorithm?).  What would you recommend as a sensible initial size in my particular case of searching for a 20-digit substring?

Comment: Statistically, you can expect that nearly all indicies will be filled up to about 10-12 digits

Comment: I think you want to start with the largest n possible while not overloading your hash table (in the worst case you need to store 10^n values).  I would try n=6 or n=7

Comment: The data set you need for this problem is extremely unlikely to fit in RAM.  You cannot ignore this fact.